# In the climax of "The Mechanical", why does Jax not do this?

Tags: robots, the-alchemy-wars

In Ian Tregillis's book *The Mechanical*, towards the climax, Jax is in the New Amsterdam forge when he is attacked by various Stemwinders and servitors.  At one point, Jax uses the piece of glass to give Free Will to one of the Clakkers, but he only does this once.  Why does Jax not use the glass to give Free Will to *any* of the other Clakkers attacking him?